# Explanation for important reserved space

Tags: sql-server

I am analysing a database

I didn't understand why reserved space is more important then used space ?

Any explication ? can I get 400 GO ?

[image]

Comment: This belongs on DBA. But, I would expect that databases would allocate a range of space that is contiguous for performance reasons on hard drives (reads are better when the data is not scattered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space Reserved is the size you setup using either:

- SSMS = Database Properties / Files Database file / Initial Size (MB)
- Alter Database [XXX] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'XXX', SIZE = ...KB)
- Autogrowth changes it as well

You can check these setting using SSMS or this query:

```
SELECT file_id, name, type_desc, physical_name, size = size/128, max_size = max_size/128
FROM sys.database_files ;
```

Space Used is the size of your existing data pages in your data file. You can use this query:

```
SELECT name, groupid, filename, 
   Cast(size/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Allocated MB],
   Cast(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Used MB],
   Cast([maxsize]/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Max Size MB],
   Cast([maxsize]/128.0-(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Available Space in MB]
FROM sysfiles
ORDER BY groupid DESC
```

Comment: Is there a way to get 400 go ?

Comment: You can always remove data but it is not a good option :) Space used is 689GB, your database need at least 689gb more or less.

Comment: unused space is 37734857 Go , can I get it as free space ?

Comment: you can shrink it but then the file will have to grow again sooner or later. it will also fragment your indexes